# Como navegar entre as abas do bootstrap através de um botão?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

Bom dia, colegas.

Como eu posso realizar a navegação entre as abas do bootstrap utilizando um botão javascript(preferencia)/jquery?

Possuo uma aba desenvolvida em bootstrap:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No final de cada aba possui um botão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu posso avançar entre as abas clicando neste botão?

Partes do código ->
Lista com os links para navegar nas abas:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs mb-3">
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="#dadosEmpresa" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link active">
  <i class="mdi mdi-book-account d-lg-none d-block"></i>
  <span class="d-none d-lg-block">Dados da Empresa</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="#cadastro" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link">
  <i class="mdi mdi-account-plus d-lg-none d-block"></i>
  <span class="d-none d-lg-block">Cadastro de Clientes e Fornecedores</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="#contasFinanceiras" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link">
  <i class="mdi mdi-account-cash d-lg-none d-block"></i>
  <span class="d-none d-lg-block">Contas Financeiras</span>
</a>
</li>
```

Exemplo de conteúdo dentro da aba:

```
<div class="tab-pane show active" id="dadosEmpresa">
<form action="#" method="POST">
   <h5 style="vertical-align: inherit;">Dados da Empresa</h5>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cnpj">CNPJ</label>
      <input>
      <span class="font-13 text-muted">Exemplo "01.234.567/8901-23"</span>
   </div>
```

Botão:

```
</form>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light waves-effect">Prosseguir para Próxima Aba</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o gatilho `.click()` na aba seguinte da que está ativa. Você consegue selecionar a aba seguinte utilizando o `id` da div onde está o conteúdo da aba ativa, já que o atributo `href` do botão da aba está relacionado ao `id` da div onde está seu conteúdo:

```
<a href="#cadastro"...
             ↓
<div id="cadastro"...
```

Basta colocar uma classe no botão "Prosseguir para Próxima Aba" para usar como seletor:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light waves-effect prox_aba">Prosseguir para Próxima Aba</button>
                                                            ↑
```

E usar o seguinte código:

```
$(function(){
   
   $(".prox_aba").on("click", function(){
      
      var id = $(this).closest(".tab-pane").attr("id"); // seleciona a div da aba ativa
                                                        // e pega o id
      
      $("ul.nav-tabs [href='#"+id+"']") // seleciona o link da aba ativa
      .closest("li")                    // seleciona a li da aba ativa
      .next()                           // seleciona a li seguinte
      .find("a")                        // busca o link
      .click();                         // dispara o click no link
      
   });
   
});
```

**Exemplo:** (execute em tela cheia)

```js
$(function(){
   
   $(".prox_aba").on("click", function(){
      
      var id = $(this).closest(".tab-pane").attr("id");
      
      $("ul.nav-tabs [href='#"+id+"']")
      .closest("li")
      .next()
      .find("a")
      .click();
      
   });
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs mb-3">
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#dadosEmpresa" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link active">
        <i class="mdi mdi-book-account d-lg-none d-block"></i>
        <span class="d-none d-lg-block">Dados da Empresa</span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#cadastro" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link">
        <i class="mdi mdi-account-plus d-lg-none d-block"></i>
        <span class="d-none d-lg-block">Cadastro de Clientes e Fornecedores</span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#contasFinanceiras" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link">
        <i class="mdi mdi-account-cash d-lg-none d-block"></i>
        <span class="d-none d-lg-block">Contas Financeiras</span>
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane show active" id="dadosEmpresa">
   <form action="#" method="POST">
      <h5 style="vertical-align: inherit;">Dados da Empresa</h5>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="cnpj">CNPJ</label>
         <input>
         <span class="font-13 text-muted">Exemplo "01.234.567/8901-23"</span>
      </div>
   </form>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-light waves-effect prox_aba">Prosseguir para Próxima Aba</button>
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane" id="cadastro">
   <form action="#" method="POST">
      <h5 style="vertical-align: inherit;">Cadastro de Clientes e Fornecedores</h5>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="cnpj">CNPJ</label>
         <input>
         <span class="font-13 text-muted">Exemplo "01.234.567/8901-23"</span>
      </div>
   </form>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-light waves-effect prox_aba">Prosseguir para Próxima Aba</button>
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane" id="contasFinanceiras">
   <form action="#" method="POST">
      <h5 style="vertical-align: inherit;">Contas Financeiras</h5>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="cnpj">CNPJ</label>
         <input>
         <span class="font-13 text-muted">Exemplo "01.234.567/8901-23"</span>
      </div>
   </form>
   </div>
</div>
```